# How do I install the correct video drivers in a new install on a macbook pro 8.2 15"?

Tags: system-installation, radeon, macbook

I have a macbook pro 8.2 15" (early 2011) and I have an issue installing Ubuntu. I have tried installing Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04. I have the same problems with all versions. I have tried both dvd install and usb install. I freed 60gb from my hard drive for Ubuntu and proceeded to install.

I can boot to the normal screen where I can choose to Try Ubuntu or Install. When I choose Install, I end up with frozen black screen. I tried installing with "nomodeset" command. At first I see something happening in text form but it still freezes soon.

Then somehow I figured out the issue might be my graphics card (this mac has ATI radeon 6490M and integrated Intel HD graphics 3000). I booted again with "radeon.modeset=0". Now I'm able to the very end of the installation procedure, but after rebooting I it gives me a window which says "the system is running in low graphics mode" and sends me to the command line.

I checked the error logs and it says something like "screens found but none have usable configuration" and some fatal error afterwards "no screens found"

So the problem is nasty. If I try to install with only "nomodeset" I won't get too far with the install, and when I install with "radeon.modeset=0" I get to install the whole thing but evidently its not working :D. After installing with "radeon.modeset=0" I even installed lynx and downloaded latest drivers from ATI web page and installed them in command line, but it wasn't much of help.

Please help me, I have been fighting with this about 14 hours now...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the Radeon/Intel switchable graphics. For instructions for installing the proprietary drivers, please see [Ubuntu Quantal Installation Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide). If you go to main page, you will also see instructions for 12.04 and 13.04.

The instructions link to a [workaround for hybrid graphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#WORKAROUND).

Be sure to follow the sections titled *Before you start* and *Removing the driver* before installing a new driver.

You may have to try both the workaround and installing the driver from the Catalyst website to see which one works for your computer. (But follow the instructions at this site. As you saw, just downloading the driver from the website is not enough.)